# Shopify UI Extension for Discount Validation

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Shopify have default Discount Code Block. When we used

```
useDiscountCodeChange
```

hook it is hitting only if the discount code is valid. I want to get the invalid discount code as well . Which hook i need to call for failed discount codes?

Tried with useDiscountCodeChange hook but working for applied discounts only.